# cmd overwrites previous logs when overflowing its height

Tags: cmd, overflow, bigdata

When I use windows command line to show big data content i only get to view a part of the output. It seems that cmd overwrites its content when overflowing its height. How can i overpass this? For example if you try to run this file with node js which resieves big-data as response you.

```
"use strict";
let http = require("http");

//Options to be used by request
var options = {
host:"demo.boundlessgeo.com",
port:"80",
path:"/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typenames=osm:placenames_medium"
};
var callback = function(response){
var body = "";
response.on("data",function(data){
    body+=data;
});
response.on("end", function(){
    //Data recieved completely
    console.log(body)
});
};
//Make the request
var req = http.request(options,callback);
req.end()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the screen buffer in right click the titlebar - *Properties* - *Layout* tab.

Comment: still it is going to 9999 max.. which means that at some point it will be overflowed.. Is this all someone can do?

Comment: See in registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console ScreenBufferSize. High order 16 bit is lines, low order 16 bits is width. Should be able to edit to 65535.